# Triple-display setup using AMD drivers

Tags: drivers, 12.10, multiple-monitors, radeon, fglrx

I am currently running a dual display setup with nVidia 8800GTS video card, on a Ubuntu 12.10 box. The current setup uses nVidia TwinView to render the image on a 1920x1200 display and 1600x1200 one.

I'm planning to add a third, 1280x1024 display to the setup. The change will require me to upgrade my GFX card to one supporting triple displays. I'll probably go with Sapphire Radeon 7770 (FLEX edition, to avoid additional active DP->DVI adapters).

Before I invest in new GFX I wanted to ask - how well the AMD drivers will support such a setup. It does not matter whether it's fglrx or the OSS ones. If I remember correctly, when running Fedora on a Radeon x800, I had 'void' areas above and below the working area on my second display. The desktop was rendered in 1920+1280 width and 1200 height (which left 176px of vertical space accessible for my cursor and windows but not displayed on the screen - I'd prefer to avoid that). It may have very well been my misconfiguration back then. Generally, are there any solutions from AMD on par with TwinView? Or is it a non-issue at all?

Also, I'm wondering about the usual stuff - hardware h264 decoding support, glitch-free flash support, any issues with Compiz/Unity?

Answer (score 1):

I've been running Eyefinity since the 5000 series came out, which allowed me to ditch the external splitter box I had previously been using. It took AMD another 8 months to add support to the Linux drivers, but they did it.

As far as I'm aware, to run three monitors from the same card, you need Eyefinity, and they need to output the same resolution. If that's changed since my 5770, I apologise, but that's my understanding of the tech, so you may need a second card. (nVidia would require a second card in any case - I checked on their website just the other day.)

Performance-wise, for general use they're great. No complaints to speak of, really. Flash is fine (installed via the Flash-Aid FF plugin), video is fine, no problems.

I'm in the Steam beta, however, and the performance in games sucks! I'm working on getting the latest drivers installed from the AMD site to see if there are any improvements, but the config isn't being kind to me. Pro tip: install from repo via Jockey or similar, and leave it at that! You get the full Catalyst control centre, and you don't have the install hassles.